# Binary code in wrong order - how to shift it properly?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, binary

I would like to give out the binary code for a number. The following code does indeed give out a "binary code", but he does it in the wrong order. For example, when I would like to print the binary code of 1, it prints "10000000" instead of "00000001". I recognized that multiplying any number by 2 shifts the binary code to the left. For example, the number 5 has the binary code "00000101", and the and the number 10 has the binary code "00001010", and so on. I thought about using this mechanism, but yet, I haven't come to the right idea.

```
for (int j = 0; j <= 7; j++) {

 if (x % 2 == 0) {
   IO.print(0);
 }
 else {
   IO.print(1);
  x = x / 2;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int j = 7; j >= 0; --j) {
    if ((x & (1 << j)) != 0) {
        IO.print("1");
    } else {
        IO.print("0");
    }
}
```

By doing a bitwise-and (using `&`) you can mask out all of bits other than the one you are checking.

You generate the "mask" by shifting a number with only bit 0 set to 1 (`1`) left.

When you do `a & b` the expression result will have a `1` bit in every position where it was `1` in both `a` and `b`.

Comment: I'm afraid he can't use it :p

Comment: If you can't use libraries and you can't compute it with primitives, then you can't do it at all.

Comment: I've found the algorithm with primitives only, but I wish I know what university he joins. I'd apply for a professor chair.

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks! Still have to understand why though. :D

Comment: @xenteros: No, that one I'm allowed to use. :-)

Comment: @Julian it works by making a mask, with only one of the bits set to 1. It uses a left shift (`<<`) to slide the 1 bit left into each bit position (by `j` bits). The `&` clears out all of the bits from `x` that don't have a corresponding `1` in the mask. When it checks whether the result is not zero, it is essentially checking just that bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, doug! Would you mind when I still gave the "accepted answer" to xenteros? He put so much effort in his answer.

Comment: @Julian it would be unfair. Accepted answer is the solution which helped you. On the other hand I know, that whatever happen, I'll skip your questions, as you can't use attached solutions.

Comment: You still owe me numers for which my solution doesn't work.

Comment: @xenteros I'm guessing negative numbers.

Comment: No, for 13.5 for example.

Comment: But like I said, I'm quite sure that it has something to do with my code. Tried it with another solution of another person, and it didn't work either, although in their code, it worked just fine.

Comment: I don't know how this question went from 1 to -1. I'm sorry if I offended anyone.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are two way - as usuall. The first one:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(x));
```

The second:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (x > 0) {
    sb.append(x%2);
    x = x/2;
}
sb.reverse();
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

OK, let me introduce you to `StringBuilder`. It's a class which efficiently appends builds a `String` which can be returned at any time with `toString()` method. The appending occurs with `append()` which can take any primitive as an argument as well as a `String`.

The code above says:

1. Create new `StringBuilder`.
2. As long, as the number is still larger then 0, append the `String` x%2.
3. Now, as you have the `String` exactly the same as you have in your current solution, you have to reverse it. It's also provided by `StringBuilder`.
4. Simply print `sb.toString()` which is the String you have just builded.

I can see, that you assume that the number has maximum 8 bits. If so, you can substitute the `StringBuffer` with a `char[8]`, fill it and then read backwards.

```
char[] buff = new char[8];
for (int j = 0; j <= 7; j++) {
    buff[j] = x%2;
    x=x/2;
}

boolean onePrinted = false;
for (int j = 7; j>=0; j--) {
    if (onePrinted) {
        IO.print(buff[j]);
    } else if (buff[j] == 1) {
        IO.print(buff[j]);
        onePrinted = true;
    }
}
if (!onePrinted) {
    IO.print(0);
}
```

OK, simpler approach for the special request of the OP.

```
int countZeros = 0;
while (x%2 == 0) {
    x = x/2;
    countZeros++;
}
int temp = 0;
while (x>0) {
    temp = temp*2;
    temp += x%2;
    x = x/2;
}
while (temp > 0) {
    System.out.print(temp%2);
    temp = temp/2;
}
for (int i = 0; i < countZeros; i++) {
    System.out.print(0);
}
```

Comment: We haven't introduced either of these methods in university yet.

Comment: There must be a way to do it only using for- and while-loops and if-else-conditionals.

Comment: So it's great moment to start using it! I strongly recommend you learning more then they tell you on the university! Otherwise you'll get into trouble.

Comment: I still wonder if there was another way to do it with just the basic tools. It's part of a much bigger task and that's the last piece that I didn't got right yet.

Comment: @Julian I gave you the solution using primitives only, however if you want to write this way, simply switch to C or assembly. :) If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking on a gray tick below the answer score. Upvote will be welcomed also

Comment: Thanks for the addition, but we aren't allowed to use that either. It hasn't been covered in the lecture yet.

Comment: I'm talking about the array here.

Comment: So what are you allowed to use? while loop and ints only? :D

Comment: Yet, we have covered only while- and for-loops, if-else-conditionals and float-numbers. Yes, that's it.

Comment: @Julian Here you are. Please check my other answer just in case you find something interesting just leave an upvote or a comment.

Comment: Part of learning programming is learning to use the language and tools before you, and finding new tools and ways to do things on your own. Don't confine yourself to the knowledge your school provides, come up with better solutions. `StringBuilder` is a very basic component of Java.

Comment: It doesn't work in my code, for whatever reason. :/ Plus, about the other discussion: It's part of a task we got from university, so of course I'm willing to only use those tools that we covered in the lecture yet. Otherwise, they wouldn't accept our solutions.

Comment: @Julian what do you mean by "it doesn't work"? It works, I have tested it and it's fine. What is your `IO`?

Comment: It still gave me the numbers in the wrong order, I have no idea why though. Must've something to do with my code, but I don't see how. It should actually work fine. The one from doug works though.

Comment: About "IO", it has something to do with the tools our university uses. I changed it when I implemented it of course.

Comment: For what input did it go wrong? I have tests which show it works.